# IE8 iframe renders simple text file as HTML , I need raw code

Tags: javascript, iframe, text, internet-explorer-8

I have  iframes that need to show  codefiles. The codefiles have .txt extention and should just show the code as text. This works perfectly on all browsers except IE8. IE8 keeps rendering the code files as HTML.

```
    <iframe id="codeFile222" 
    width="100%" height="200px"
    marginheight="0" frameborder="0" 
    src="http://mrsbos.wikispaces.com/file/view/guessNumber.txt"
    name="codeFile222" 
    onload="autoResize('codeFile222');changeColor('codeFile222')"
    >
```

Any idea what I could do about this, to also make it work in IE8

Comment: What is the `Content-Type` header value from your web server?  That determines how the browser should display the resource.

Comment: Hi, How can I find out what the Content Type is? and can I possibly change this? By the way , it doesn't have this problem with the other browsers like chrome and firefox. Can they have a different Content Type?

Comment: see Ken's answer.  As he suggests, Fiddler is a good tool for this, and he provides an explanation as to why it may not matter in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Content-Type` HTTP header indicates the [MIME type](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) of the resource (a web page, image, or download). For HTML pages, the MIME type is normally `text/html`, and for text files, it is normally `text/plain`.

The server does send `text/plain;charset=utf-8` for your text files (as, for example, shown in [Firebug](//getfirebug.com/)'s Net panel when performing a hard reload of a file using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>). However, Internet Explorer, unlike other web browsers, will see HTML in the file and second-guess the server ([Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Because this can have security implications, yet Microsoft didn't want to risk breaking backward compatibility with older sites (by making IE's behavior consistent with that of other browsers), Internet Explorer 8 and newer support an `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header to disable the HTML detection in this case. However, on such a site as Wikispaces, you might not have the option to send the header, and in any case, the header will have no effect in Internet Explorer 6 and 7.

On Wikispaces, it probably makes sense to use the provided source-code formatting feature (see [wikitext help page](http://help.wikispaces.com/Wikitext#Code)):

```
[[code format="javascript"]]
alert('hello, world');
[[code]]
```

And if you want to store the code on a separate page, you can include it from the page that people are actually supposed to read ([Wikispaces include help page](http://help.wikispaces.com/Wikitext#Contents%20of%20Another%20Wiki%20Page)). This is called [transclusion](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transclusion):

```
[[include page="PAGENAME"]]
```

Failing that, a good option may be to HTML-escape the code (using a few text replacements) and insert it between `<pre></pre>`. Then you would be uploading an HTML file (file extension of `.htm` or `.html`). For the purpose of explanation, here is a simple JavaScript function that does HTML escaping:

```
function htmlEscape(text) {
    // Absolutely necessary
    text = text.replace(/&/g, '&amp;'); // Has to go first
    text = text.replace(/</g, '&lt;');

    // Not needed for your specific case, yet would be good to include
    text = text.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    text = text.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
    text = text.replace(/'/g, '&#39;'); // '&apos;' is only OK in XHTML and in HTML5
    return text;
}
```

Comment: turnToText2=function(id){
if(window.XMLHttpRequest && document.all){

var text=null;
var obj=document.getElementById(id);
var y=null;

 y=(obj.contentDocument|| obj.contentWindow);


var head =y.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var texth=head.innerHTML;
console.log("head:"+head);
console.log("texth:"+texth);
text=y.body.innerHTML;
text=texth+text;

console.log("text:"+text);



while(text.indexOf("<")!=-1){
    text=text.replace("<","&lt;");
}
while(text.indexOf(">")!=-1){
    text=text.replace(">","&gt;");
} 
     
if(y!=null){
y.body.innerHTML=text;
}

}
else{
console.log("NOT IE:");
}
}

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. I have now used a turnToText function like you suggested. At first the result would just show me the HTML tags in plain text but not the  scripts. Clearly the browser had put the script tags and its contents in a <head> tag. So I could pull them out of there and add them onto the rest of the code . My function looks  now like this. I just need to give the result a better layout by adding in nonwhite break spaces line breaks etc.

Comment: thanks a lot

By the way, I will also make use of the code tags in wikispaces, because it does improve clarity with the different colors. So thanks for that. I do also like the toggle effect, that I can create with my own hyperlinks and iframes, so I wanted this to work on all browsers as well.Thanks a lot , see below for my proper response.

Comment: It seems that IE 11, 12 and Edge now ignore X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

Answer (score 1):

The link you have provided (mrsbos.wikispaces.com/file/view/guessNumber.txt) has text/plain as content-type so that one's ok.

To find out what content-type is you can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) or simply right-click the page and select Page info or something similar (depending on browser).

My guess would be that IE tries to be smart about auto-detecting the content, sees a `<script>` tag and assume it is html.

In these cases you will have to encode the content, optionally if possible present a html page instead from server where the source code is in `<pre>`-tags.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has existed for a while, and unfortunately there isn't really a proper fix. One thing that may work is wrapping everything inside the `iframe` with a `<pre>` tag using Javascript, but that is a bit of a hack.

There's more info on the problem at [www.howtocreate.co.uk](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/wrongWithIE/?chapter=Content-type%3a%20text/plain), I'll reproduce the body of the article here:

> While we are on the subject of the Content-type HTTP header, XHTML is
>   not the only one that IE gets wrong. It even treats plain text
>   incorrectly. If you send a header that says that you are using plain
>   text, but it contains something that IE thinks is HTML, it will ignore
>   your header, and render it as HTML. So your text file that you
>   carefully prepared gets converted into a run-in paragraph that is
>   almost unreadable, with bits missing and formatting lost.
>
> Why would they do it? Because occasionally, HTML pages are incorrectly
>   served as plain text by web servers. And if that happens, this will
>   make IE render it as HTML. This sounds like a good idea, but what this
>   means is that authors who make these pages do not realise that their
>   page is incorrectly being served as text, because when they check it
>   in IE, it looks like it is working. Browsers that correctly comply
>   with the content type that the page specifies will see the page source
>   instead of its contents. And also, it means that many text files are
>   incorrectly mangled because IE thinks they are HTML.
>
> Either way, someone loses out. But if IE did not ignore the text
>   Content-type header, the author would realise there was a problem, and
>   fix the server instead. The page would work in all browsers, and IE
>   would not screw up text files.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the the explanation as to why and how. At least it makes sense now at some level. Anyway I am glad explorer 10 does not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have now used a turnToText function like you suggested. At first the result would just show me the HTML tags in plain text but not the  scripts. Clearly the browser had put the script tags and its contents in a head tag. So I could pull them out of there and add them onto the rest of the code . My function looks  now like this. I just need to give the result a better layout by adding in nonwhite break spaces line breaks etc.

```
    turnToText2=function(id){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest && document.all){

    var text=null;
    var obj=document.getElementById(id);
    var y=null;

     y=(obj.contentDocument|| obj.contentWindow);


    var head =y.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var texth=head.innerHTML;

    text=y.body.innerHTML;
    text=texth+text;

    while(text.indexOf("<")!=-1){
    text=text.replace("<","&lt;");
    }
    while(text.indexOf(">")!=-1){
        text=text.replace(">","&gt;");
    } 

    if(y!=null){
   y.body.innerHTML=text;
   }

   } else{
    console.log("NOT IE:");
    }
    }
```

thanks a lot

By the way, I will also make use of the code tags in wikispaces, because it does improve clarity with the different colors. So thanks for that. I do also like the toggle effect, that I can create with my own hyperlinks and iframes, so I wanted this to work on all browsers as well.